# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar', in Xamarine Android .    I am using Visual Studio 17.
And also
When i am intalling below package from Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio 2017 for Xamarine.Android i am getting erorr below.
Error:
Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView 27.0.2.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably a build issue, clean your solution, delete bin and obj folder and then rebuild, see if it persists.
You can also try restarting VS once.
If it persists you might be missing the Appcompat library, which you can install via nuget.

Comment: I have tried above solution but it didn't work.
P.S: I edited my question.

Comment: Did you try to install that nuget on the PCL/Shared/NET Standard project?

Comment: Please install that nuget into the <YourProjectName>.Android project